# Do there exist elliptic curves over schemes which have all primes as residue characteristics?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

It's well known that there are no elliptic curves over Spec $\mathbb{Z}$, but it's unclear (to me at least) if the proof generalizes.

My question is: If $S$ is a connected scheme such that has every prime as a residue characteristic, then can there exist an elliptic curve over $S$?

Comment: @KestutisCesnavicius Of course! Thank you for pointing that out! Well that was resolved quickly.

Comment: @KestutisCesnavicius If you'd like to post that as an answer I can accept it and nobody will have to read my stupid question anymore :-D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there can. Choose any elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with potential good reduction (for instance, a curve with potential CM) and pass to a number field $K$ over which the reduction is everywhere good. Then $E_K$ extends to an elliptic curve over the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, and the latter has all primes as residue characteristics.

Answer (score 19):

More interesting is the question of which fields admit what sorts of elliptic curves having everywhere good reduction. For example, how about quadratic fields? Here are a couple of results.

**Theorem** (Rohrlich [1]) Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field and $j$ the invariant of some fixed isomorphism class of elliptic curves with complex multiplication by the ring of integers of $K$. Put $F=\mathbb Q(j)$ and $H=K(j)$. Then there is an elliptic curve with invariant $j$, defined over $F$, which has good reduction at every place of $F$ if and only if the discriminant $−d$ of $K$ is divisible by at least two primes congruent to 3 modulo 4.

**Theorem** (Setzer [2]) There are no elliptic curves having good reduction everywhere over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-m})$ for $m=1,2,3,5,6,7,10,13,14,15,17,21,22,\ldots$ .

1. Rohrlich, David E., Elliptic curves with good reduction everywhere.
   *J. London Math. Soc.* (2) **25** (1982), no. 2, 216–222.
2. Setzer, Bennett, Elliptic curves over complex quadratic fields.
   *Pacific J. Math.* **74** (1978), no. 1, 235–250.

Answer (score 7):

Another perspective: Let $K$ be any number field and let $E$ be any elliptic curve over $K$ with $j$-invariant in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Then there is an extension $L$ of $K$ such that $E \times_K L$ extends to an elliptic curve over $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Proof: By properness of the stack $\overline{M}_{1,1}$, there is some $L$ so that we get a stable genus one curve with one marked point over $\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathcal{O}_L$. We just need to rule out the possibility that some fibers are nodal. If the fiber over a prime $\pi$ of $\mathcal{O}_L$ is nodal, than a computation with Tate curves shows that $v_{\pi}(j)<0$, contradicting that $j \in \mathcal{O}_L$. $\square$

I think it is worth bringing this up, as well as the CM solutions above, because there are many more integral $j$-invariants than there are $j$-invariants with CM.

Comment: That's a fancy way to do it. :) The fact that elliptic curves with integral $j$-invariant have everywhere good reduction over an extension field (which is iff) follows easily if char $\mathfrak p\ge5$ using the Weierstrass eqn, and can even be done for 2 and 3 with more work. There's also the Serre-Tate (Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich) criterion which says good reduction iff the action of Galois on appropriate torsion is unramified. So adjoining some torsion gives a field of everywhere good reduction. In particular, I think you can take your $L$ to be something like $K(E[15])$.